# FInd buttons in a perticular row using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have two questions.
I have a dynamically generated table.
The last cell in each row is a button. The table is editable. With a little help and learning about jquery I understood that I can get the row an column of a cell that has been clicked.
What I would like to do is that the button in that column should change its text to update and upon clicking it Id like to get the content from that row and update it in the server using a python script.

How do I go about finding the button in that particular row?
And question two how to collect all data from the row which has been updated and pack it into a JSON object?

My table generation is dynamic and since its a template  (Django) I cant give a class to that particular  element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to find and get row data without class, DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/fBDZk/

## JQUERY

```
$('table input[type=button]').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent('td').siblings().each(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

## HTML

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>a1</td>
    <td>a2</td>
    <td>a3</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Submit" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>b1</td>
    <td>b2</td>
    <td>b3</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Submit" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c1</td>
    <td>c2</td>
    <td>c3</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Submit" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>d1</td>
    <td>d2</td>
    <td>d3</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Submit" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>e1</td>
    <td>e2</td>
    <td>e3</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Submit" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks that works fine. About sending all the row data if you could help me?

Comment: I cannot test that data sending part :(

Comment: Check here for how to create json object...http://iviewsource.com/codingtutorials/getting-started-with-javascript-object-notation-json-for-absolute-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery**

```
$('table input[type=button]').on('click', function(){
    aRow = $(this).closest('tr');
    aRow.find('td').each(function() {
        aData[] = this.text();
    });
    jData = JSON.stringify(aData);
    $.post('data_processor.php',{myJSONdata: jData});
});
```